# how to install Jdk 7 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java

I''ve downloaded tar file from oracle server but I don't know how to install it on my ubuntu linux system.
Could you please provide step by step details on how to install it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If there is some trouble with installing downloaded files, try to get packages over the command line:

1. Open a new terminal.
2. Set this command: `sudo apt-get install icedtea–7-plugin openjdk–7-jre`

Done.

Comment: Note that OP probably asks for installing proprietary JDK, not OpenJDK.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a repository to your accepted sources. This is the one I used:

http://www.enqlu.com/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-78-jdk-and.html

The site gives you step by step instructions. Simple and easy.

Answer (score 0):

Use following link and follow the given instructions:

http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/